# How can I insert all items in a list into postgres at once?

Tags: postgresql, asyncpg, executemany

I have a python list, which has ~20k items in it. These are integers.

I would like to INSERT all these integers.

For integers that already exist, I would like to increment the second row, that we'll call `amount` by one.

Since there are ~20k items, it seems very slow to iter through all of them and insert them one by one. Is there any way to do this in one query?

I'm using the `asyncpg` library.

Comment: Where is this "list" of yours? is it inside a Postgre SQL script/batch, or is it in application-code (_outside_ of Posgtgres?). We can't help you without seeing any code.

Comment: it's a python list. sorry I didn't specify that

Comment: Is the field you are inserting the `integer` into a primary key or unique constraint? You don't have to iterate one by one, you could do it batches if it turns out you need to do some modification of the insert/update.

Comment: unique constraint.

Comment: Take a look at [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause for `INSERT`. Still think that doing this in batches would be the way to go.